# How to ensure Adobe Reader does not prompt to save .pdf when view a .pdf file that was created by concatenating .pdf files with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am currently using iText 2.1.7 to append one .pdf file to another. My code is similar to many of the concatenation examples I have found online, with the addition of adding a bookmark for the trailing pdf file and preserving the existing bookmarks.

Recently a user has found that, after opening the concatenated file and then closing, they are prompted to save the file. It appears that newer versions of Adobe Reader now detect .pdf errors, and fix it, resulting in the save prompt.

In creating a test program for this, I found that it is the trailing bookmark and adjusting existing bookmarks that is the problem. Is there a way to ensure that the user isn't prompted to save after view a file produced when concatenating one .pdf file to another with iText?

The test can be run with "java TestPdfConcat ***pdf_file_1*** ***pdf_file_2*** ***optional_trailing_bookmark***"

If the trailing bookmark is omitted, then the resulting concatenated .pdf does not prompt the user to save upon closing.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class TestPdfConcat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File originalPDF = new File(args[0]);
        File trailingPDF = new File(args[1]);
        String trailingBookmark = null;
        if (args.length > 2)
            trailingBookmark = args[2];

        PdfReader reportReader = null;
        try {
            reportReader = new PdfReader(originalPDF.getPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // Get bookmarks for original report.
        ArrayList master = (ArrayList) SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reportReader);
        if (master == null)
            master = new ArrayList();
        int reportPages = reportReader.getNumberOfPages();
        PdfReader trailingReader = null;
        try {
            trailingReader = new PdfReader(trailingPDF.getPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        trailingReader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
        int trailingPages = trailingReader.getNumberOfPages();
        List bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(trailingReader);
        if (trailingBookmark != null) {
            // Add trailing bookmark.
            System.out.println("Add bookmark, " + trailingBookmark + ", to trailing pdf.");
            if (bookmarks == null)
                bookmarks = new ArrayList();
            // If trailing pdf has existing bookmarks, shift them for the appended pdf.
            if (!bookmarks.isEmpty()) {
                if (reportPages != 0) {
                    SimpleBookmark.shiftPageNumbers(bookmarks, reportPages, null);
                }
            }

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Title", trailingBookmark);
            map.put("Action", "GoTo");
            map.put("Page", Integer.toString(reportPages + 1));
            bookmarks.add(map);
            // Add to existing bookmarks.
            master.addAll(bookmarks);
        }


        // Append to original document
        System.out.println("Append " + trailingPDF.getName() + " to " + originalPDF.getName());
        Document document = new Document(reportReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        PdfCopy writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("Concatenated.pdf", true));
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        document.open();

        PdfImportedPage page;
        // Add original report pages.
        System.out.println("Original report has " + reportPages + " page(s).");
        for (int i = 0; i < reportPages;) {
            page = writer.getImportedPage(reportReader, ++i);
            try {
                writer.addPage(page);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (BadPdfFormatException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        // Add trailing pdf pages.
        System.out.println("Trailing pdf has " + trailingPages + " page(s).");
        for (int j = 0; j < trailingPages;) {
            page = writer.getImportedPage(trailingReader, ++j);
            try {
                writer.addPage(page);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (BadPdfFormatException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        if (!master.isEmpty()) {
            writer.setOutlines(master);
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adobe built the original PDF spec and multiple `%%EOF` were and still are part of it so I'm pretty sure that's not the problem. Usually whenever I see this there's actually a problem of "garbage data" at the end of a PDF. For instance, in a web-based context where it is streamed to a browser there's some extra HTML or exception messages included in the stream. I'd start there instead.

Comment: I compared a sample concatenated .pdf file from before and after it is saved by Adobe Reader. You're right, the %%EOF markers were preserved, but there were quite a few other changes throughout the file, starting with a change of the first line, %PDF-1.4 to %PDF-1.6. My knowledge of the .pdf file format is rudimentary. I was depending on iText to create a valid .pdf.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF created by your code.

Comment: Whenever I've opened a corrupt PDF (that I've intentionally made corrupt) Adobe Acrobat has always saved it as a version 1.6 PDF, I think that's just a default setting in the program. iText will do what you tell it do. You absolutely can make corrupt PDFs using it however that usually only happens when you are in "advanced mode" and aren't following the spec. It might seem weird but iText cannot actually make PDF _files_, it can only write PDF commands to a `Stream` that you provide. This is why mkl asked for a sample PDF to help us see what you are seeing.

Comment: There is nothing in your problem description that unequivocally puts the blame with your PDF file even. Does this happen on all systems with all PDFs you create with this code? Also look at the system around the PDFs you create, could it be that the PDF file downloaded was damaged in some way en route to the user? So, get us a PDF file so you can be sure that's really the problem or whether you need to look at other parts of your workflow.

Comment: The concatenation code above is used to add a trailing page to a .pdf report. I have tested a number of reports, and all of the samples I have generated so far  will prompt for saving at closing time. I have created a test concatenated output .pdf file that I can share, but don't have a place to share it publicly.

Comment: I have added a link to a sample .pdf file in the previous comment. I have also tried upgrading to use iText 5.5.8, but still get prompted to save on the resulting file.

Comment: That link gives me a 403 error

Comment: @LanceInHopkins Access to your sample file is denied.

Comment: I have removed the link to a sample .pdf. A .pdf can be created from the standalone test class above.